# Custom dynamoDB model nested structure for dynamoDB using serverless.yml

Tags: serverless

I want to make a structure like given below.

```
{
  "key1": {
           "key2": "uuid" //uuid here
       }
}
```

how to make this on serverless.yml file with indentation.